# Changing IE Proxy in C#

Tags: internet-explorer, proxy, fiddlercore

I am using FiddlerCore to write some automate test cases. THe problem which i am facing is sometimes fiddler does not shut down properly and hence the proxy remains set in IE. And the next time a test runs the pages does not load, as fiddler is closed and proxy is set. Is there a way that i can change the IE proxy through code. I want that no proxy option should be selected, as we can see when we go to Tools -> Internet options -> Connections -> LAN settings : No check box is selected. How can i achieve this using C# ? I have seen some posts on this, but nothing is specific to this requirement.

THanks!

Comment: If your app is throwing an exception and isn't shutting down properly, what makes you think that your app's code is going to be able to run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing proxy settings programmatically in Windows for DSL connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896318/changing-proxy-settings-programmatically-in-windows-for-dsl-connections)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you set up Fiddler as a system proxy by calling something similar like:

```
FiddlerApplication.Startup(9999, FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default);
```

When your application exits make sure to call something like:

```
if (FiddlerApplication.IsStarted())
{
    FiddlerApplication.oProxy.PurgeServerPipePool();
    FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
}
```

to make sure your system settings get restored.